# How to retrieve "simpSessionId" in spring boot controller?

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, websocket, stomp, spring-session

Front end : Angular

Back end  : Spring boot

I'm able to get the simpSessionId, with the below EventListeners

1. SessionConnectEvent (when app is launched from browser)
2. SessionDisconnectEvent (when app is closed from browser)

Once the Stomp session is connected, i'm not able to retrieve the "simpSessionId".

I have a requirement to retrieve the "simpSessionId" in spring controller, whenever there is a REST call from angular.

I have tried injecting ChannelSecurityInterceptor in controller, but no luck.

Is there a way we to read the hearbeat messages from Angular to spring in controller ?

Answer (score 0):

In your Spring REST controller, you would be having handlers which are annotated with mapping of the web request to your handler method like so

```
@<Request_type>Mapping
your_handler_function() {
....
}
```

Now in this function use 
`RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId();` to get the details of the particular web request. It being a static method you do not need to inject anything.